# Zipping multiple folders and files in one output using java

Tags: java, file, directory, zip

So iam working on a project where i get to a point when i need to zip multiple folders (4folders to be specific) and one file in one output.zip file using java
So is there anyway for me to do it and by the way putting all the folders and file in one directory and then zipping it doesn't give the same result in other words the folders have to be in root level of the zip file

Comment: Can you use libraries or only clean java?

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions.
This one for example:

```java
public static void zipDirectory(ZipOutputStream zos, File fileToZip, String parentDirectoryName) throws Exception
{
    if (fileToZip == null || !fileToZip.exists())
    {
        return;
    }

    String zipEntryName = fileToZip.getName();
    if (parentDirectoryName!=null && !parentDirectoryName.isEmpty())
    {
        zipEntryName = parentDirectoryName + "/" + fileToZip.getName();
    }

    // If we are dealing with a directory:
    if (fileToZip.isDirectory())
    {
        System.out.println("+" + zipEntryName);

        if(parentDirectoryName == null) // if parentDirectory is null, that means it's the first iteration of the recursion, so we do not include the first container folder
        {
            zipEntryName = "";
        }

        for (File file : fileToZip.listFiles()) // we iterate over all the folders/files and archive them by keeping the structure too.
        {
            zipDirectory(zos, file, zipEntryName);
        }
    } else // If we are dealing with a file, then we zip it directly
        {
        System.out.println("   " + zipEntryName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileToZip);
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(zipEntryName));
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

then you could use this function like this:

```java
try
{
    File directoryToBeZipped = new File("C:\\New\\test");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\New\\test\\archive.zip");
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
    zipDirectory(zos, directoryToBeZipped, null);
    zos.flush();
    fos.flush();
    zos.close();
    fos.close();
    

} catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or you could use the [ZeroTurnAround ZIP Library](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip). And do this in one line:

```java
ZipUtil.pack(new File("D:\\sourceFolder\\"), new File("D:\\generatedZipFile.zip"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dead easy way (though you'll get warnings about proprietary classes)

```
final String[] ARGS = { "-cfM", "x.zip", "folder1", "folder2", "folder3", "folder4", "file.txt" };
sun.tools.jar.Main.main(ARGS);
```

It might be worth getting a similar thing that won't give you warnings